# How to make QScrollArea resize when there is a QTableView in it (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, qtableview, qscrollarea

I have a QScrollArea with a widget containing a QTableView.  When other widgets in the QScrollArea are resized (enlarged) the QScrollArea should expand to accommodate the larger size. But instead, the QScrollArea sizing remains static, and the QTableView is contracted.

This behaviour ONLY occurs when there is a QTableView (or QTableWidget) in the QScrollArea widget - I can't reproduce it when other widget types are used.
And in more inexplicable (to me!) behaviour, when the second widget's contents are set to hidden on startup, the issue disappears and QScrollArea behaves as exptected (see commented lines in code below)

Image before resizing:

[image: Image before resizing]

Image showing unwanted resizing behaviour:

[image]

Image indicatively showing wanted resizing behaviour. QScrollArea scroll bar triggers to accommodate additional bottom widget space (off the bottom of the scroll bar area).  In this example the Qtableview is still being truncated, and the QScrollArea is not actually expanding, but visually it indicates the kind of behaviour wanted:

[image]

Please can anyone help suggest what might be going on?

The code below is a minimum reproducible example

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget, QLabel,QScrollArea,
                               QApplication, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem)


class WidgetWithTable(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # table widget
        table_widget = QTableWidget(5, 2)
        for i in range(5):
            for j in range(2):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(f"{i + 1}-{j + 1}")
                table_widget.setItem(i, j, item)

        # another_widget
        another_widget = QPushButton('Change the Scroll Area Size')
        another_widget.clicked.connect(self.toggle_size)

        # a widget to force resizing
        self.resizing_label = QLabel('\n\nClicking the button should expand the QScrollArea, not contract the QTableView.  If this label is set hidden at the start, the desired behaviour occurs.\n\n')
        self.resizing_label.setWordWrap(True)
        for w in [another_widget, self.resizing_label]:
            w.setMaximumWidth(300)

        # hiding the label on start up achieves desired behaviour;
        # leaving the label shown reproduces the unwanted behaviour.
        # self.resizing_label.hide()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(table_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(another_widget)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.resizing_label)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def toggle_size(self):
        self.resizing_label.setVisible(not self.resizing_label.isVisible())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication()

    test_widget = WidgetWithTable()

    scroll_widget = QScrollArea()
    scroll_widget.setWidgetResizable(True)
    scroll_widget.setWidget(test_widget)
    scroll_widget.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: If you watch carefully, the initial size of the window is different when the label is shown or not, as the size hint of the scroll area contents eventually propagate to the top level window to a certain extent. Widgets normally have a `sizeHint()` (the preferred size) that still allows them to be smaller than that size. When the label is not initially shown, the window (and the scroll area) is small, and showing the label requires the scroll contents to expand. When the label is previously shown, the window is large enough, and doesn't need to "expand" the contents more.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante.  Your comment accurately explains the show/hide behaviour though, but it still leaves the main issue that the QScrollArea size doesn't adjust when there is a QTableView in the widget. Is there a way to trigger resizing of the QScrollArea dynamically? .update() and .adjustSize() don't appear to have any effect.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what issue you're referring to, can you please provide screenshots of the before/after and include an explanation of what you expect it to do?

Comment: I've edited the question with images; the code should also be able to reproduce it.  Apologies if my question isn't clear enough - the issue is how to make a QScrollArea resize to handle size changes of widgets in the area, so that the QScrollArea expands rather than contracting the widgets themselves.

Comment: There are various possible solutions for what you're asking, but which one to choose depends on your actual needs. As you can see in the last image (and as partially explained in my initial comment), the two *views* have different sizes, and those sizes are adapted by/react to many aspects. In the last image, the scroll area resizes its contents because the view cannot be smaller than it already is. Then, you have to ask yourself many questions: how large should *initially* be the view? what should happen if the scroll area is large enough to show everything and the label is hidden? Are you »

Comment: » *completely* sure that the initial size of the view should always remain the same? How should it react to *any* change in size of any of its sibling widgets? Note that *any* change includes changes in size *requirements*, *hints* and *policies*. You could probably just try a simple `self.table_widget.setMinimumSize(self.table_widget.sizeHint())`, but that will not ensure that you'll get what you want if the window is then made larger (thus allowing the view to expand) and then the label is shown, because you'll probably get the same "problem" you see right now. That would lead us to use »

Comment: » `setFixedSize()` instead, but that wouldn't probably be a good idea (unless you are sure that the table will always have very few rows and columns), as the user would expect the view to become larger when resizing the windows, making interaction much easier, and setting a fixed (and relatively small) size for a view using a large model is a terrible idea, from the ux perspective.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add the comments.  Working from what you've said and a bit of trial and error, I have found that manually resizing each individual widget achieves the desired behaviour. In my actual use case there are more widgets, and the table row count is dynamic, so this approach works.  Really appreicate your comments.